# How to save the custom lookup record in an object when we are using lighting record form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I am trying to save the lookup selected record but not getting save and he other fields are getting save due to lighting record form .Pls help me

```
<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <!-- Your lightning-input-field components here -->
        <c-a-b-h-f-l-source-lookuplwc onlookupupdate={HandleSourceLookup}></c-a-b-h-f-l-source-lookuplwc>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <!-- More lightning-input-field components here -->
        <c-a-b-h-f-l-sub-source-lookuplwc get-source-id={selectedSubSourceId} onlookupupdate={HandleSubSourceLookup}></c-a-b-h-f-l-sub-source-lookuplwc>     
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
    <lightning-button
        class="slds-m-top_small"
        label="Cancel"
        onclick={handleCancel}
    ></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button
        class="slds-m-top_small"
        type="submit"
        label="Save"
    ></lightning-button>
</div>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Right now we can only speculate since there is not enough information here.

Comment: One option is that the user does not have write access to the given field.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely more detailed info from your use case would be of help here. But based on the info you have provided i have following suggestions:

1. If the lookup field is exposed on UI under the  tag then it behaves in the similar fashion as any lookup field behaves on SF UI.
2. If you want to do some customization before setting the lookup field value then you need to override the default submit behavior of the form as below:

   handleSubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
   const fields = event.detail.fields;
   fields.Street = '32 Prince Street';
   this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
   }